# Keep getting 400 error(Bad Request) while calling an api

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am calling an get api:-

```
function getvalue() {
    return  $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: '/api/value/:number'
    });
}
```

I am calling It in my directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.components')
        .directive('product', product);

product.$inject = ['$http','$timeout','ApiServices'];

function product($http, $timeout, ApiServices) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
        },

        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.product = {};

              scope.getproductvalue = function () {
                    ApiServices.getproductvalue().then(
                        function (response) {
                      scope.product.value = scope.product.a + " " +scope.product.b + " " +scope.product.c; 
                        });
               };
                scope.getproductvalue();
        },
        templateUrl: 'js/components/misc/product.html'
    };
  }

})();
```

I keep getting this error:-

```
GET http://localhost:3001/api/product/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

I am getting the value of a,b,c from different api.

Can anyone tell me why I keep getting this error?

Comment: Bad request means- your request content is exactly same as API is expecting. So check first what format is required for making API call. `:number` check is it **string** or **Number**?

Comment: You have getvalue() in your API but you're calling getproductvalue() in the directive.

Comment: 10.4.1 400 Bad Request

The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

Comment: :number is a string formed by:- scope.product.value. Also it is getproductvalue. I typed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstand with angular rout URL and API calling URL.

Your http URL format should be

```
url: '/api/value ? number = '+18
```

Comment: should it be:-url: '/api/value/:number' or url: '/api/value/' +number